# How to use Sprite instead of img src

Tags: css-sprites

I am trying to use sprite images
I have a very basic link

```
<td align="center">
    <img alt="my alt text" src="/Assets/t/myImage.gif" />
</td>
```

I am struggling for a while, tying to change this and making it use an image in my sprite instead of the src

Comment: The technique called CSS sprites has a very limited scope in which it is possible and useful. Are you sure you can (and should) use sprites for this? What does your image show?

Comment: I have a lot of them in my page and I managed to have nearly everything done but this one that is inside a cell in my table

Answer (score 0):

Here's an simple example of using sprite images.

The basic idea is to use background image on a fixed sized element (in the example it's an `a` tag with width/height 20px).  Then positioning the image using `background-position` to select the sprite you need.  The `:hover` selector is used to pick yet another sprite when moused over. Normally you'd have multiple links all using a different sprite from the one image.

css:

```
a.sprite_button
{
    background-image:url(toolbar.png);
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
a#button1         { background-position:0px 0px; }
a#button1:hover   { background-position:0px 20px; }
```

html:

```
<a href="blah" class="sprite_button" id="button1"></a>
```

Comment: Why should I use all this code?
it is a lot to do !!!
I do not need a list. I have some images in my page and one of them is inside a cell <td> ... </td>

Comment: @user I'm still not convinced you *need* sprites. What's so special about the `td`? What do the other images on your page look like?

Comment: I just ended up using a span with display block instead of image and it is working
Thank you for your help

Comment: @user.  I'm not sure I understand your question then.  You say you have a basic link but it's just an image in a table.  Normally sprites are used to flip images on mouse over, or to load a whole set of images from a single file (so that a row of buttons don't appear one by one as they load for example).  If you just want an image in a cell, I agree with Pekka, why do you want to use sprites?  Can you explain in more detail the problem you're facing.

Comment: I've simplified the example even more to try and highlight how it works.

Comment: As said, I ended up using this : <a href="blah"> <span style="display:block, backgroud_image....> </span></a>

Answer (score 0):

sprites are large images containing more than one graphic, which are used in CSS as background-image. They are placed as background on block elements which are also sized with CSS using Width and Height. Then, using background-position, the background image is placed where it should be. The image is cropped according to those coordinates and element size, and the rest is ignored (used for other element backgrounds).

For example you have pretty buttons, which have a normal state, a mouse hover state, and an active state (pressed). Just place all 3 images one below the other, in one single image file.

```
button  {display: block; width: 100px; height: 50px; background-image: url(yourImage.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0 0;}
button:HOVER {background-position: 0 -50px;}
button.active {background-position: 0 -100px;}
```

This will also eliminate the situation when new background image has to be loaded when the state is changed, meanwhile leaving an ugly button for half a second.